# How to use Ansible Style dynamic inventory with Nornir?

Tags: python, ansible

I want to move from Ansible to Nornir. In Ansbile I use **dynamic inventory**, where I use this python script to reference the host_var folder:

```
import json
import yaml
import glob

groups = {}

for hostfilename in glob.glob('./host_vars/*.yml'):
    with open(hostfilename, 'r') as hostfile:
        host = yaml.load(hostfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        for hostgroup in host['host_groups']:
            if hostgroup not in groups.keys():
                groups[ hostgroup ] = { 'hosts': [] }
            groups[ hostgroup ]['hosts'].append( host['hostname'] )

print(json.dumps(groups))
```

Question:
How can I use my existing Ansible Inventory in Nornir.

***nornir.plugins.inventory.ansible.AnsibleInventory*** can only be used with 1x host.yaml file not with many, at least this is my understanding

**Edit:** Goal is to create always new Inventory files on every run. The workflow would be to generate the inventory yaml files in host_vars and then use it during the play.

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks
F.

Comment: Use `ansible-inventory` on the command line to dump your dynamic inventory to a static one then import it in whatever format is needed by your tool. Else re-implement your dynamic inventory inside your new tool if it is supported.

Comment: thanks, my goal is to always create dynamic inventory on the fly. This is how I do in Ansible

I now search a method how to do this with Python/Nornir to not change much of my logic

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want each yaml file in the host_vars folder to be interpreted as one host and its data. This feature is not part of base Nornir, but can be implemented via a custom inventory plugin.

The custom inventory plugin should implement a load() method that returns an Inventory-type object that Nornir can then use normally (see here for an example of the [SimpleInventory](https://github.com/nornir-automation/nornir/blob/develop/nornir/plugins/inventory/simple.py) implementation). I came up with this snippet adapted from the code that was given:

```py
import os
import yaml
import glob
import pathlib
from nornir.core.inventory import (
    Inventory,
    Hosts,
    Host,
    Groups,
    Group)

def map_host_data(host_dict):
    return({
        'hostname' : host_dict['hostname'],
        'port': host_dict.get('port',22),
        'username' : host_dict['username'],
        'password' : host_dict['password'],
        'platform' : host_dict['platform'],
        'data'     : host_dict.get('data', None)
    })


class DynamicInventory:
    def __init__(self, inventory_dir: str = "host_vars/") -> None:
        self.inventory_dir = pathlib.Path(inventory_dir).expanduser()

    def load(self):
        hosts = Hosts()
        groups = Groups()
        for hostfilename in glob.glob(f"{self.inventory_dir}/*.yaml"):
            with open(hostfilename,'r') as hostfile:
                host_name = os.path.basename(hostfilename).replace('.yaml','')
                host = yaml.load(hostfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
                for hostgroup in host['host_groups']:
                    if hostgroup not in groups.keys():
                        group = Group(name=hostgroup)
                        groups[hostgroup] = group
                hosts[host_name] = Host(name=host_name, **map_host_data(host))

        return Inventory(hosts=hosts,groups=groups,defaults={})
```

I'm assuming you're using Nornir >= 3 (which you really should), so don't forget to register your plugin if using it on your configuration. Assuming you put the above code under plugins/inventory.py:

```py
from nornir import InitNornir
from plugins.inventory import DynamicInventory
from nornir.core.plugins.inventory import InventoryPluginRegister

InventoryPluginRegister.register("DynamicInventoryPlugin",DynamicInventory)

nr = InitNornir(inventory={'plugin': 'DynamicInventoryPlugin'},
                runner={'plugin': 'threaded','options': {'num_workers': 20}})
```

This of course ignores some features (such as setting defaults), but can be modified to add more features that better match your current setup.